# Zombie ssh process using python subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, popen, zombie-process

I have a script which runs a test case using 2 different machines. The test requires some commands ran on machine 1 before the commands ran on machine 2 and then machine 1 sends data to machine 2. The goal is to be able to run the test from either machine, so I figured I would ssh to machine 1 and do the commands there, then ssh to machine 2 and do the commands there... I'm trying to avoid paramiko because I don't want that extra dependency, so I found this nifty piece of code which kind of gets the job done:

```
def executeRemoteCommand(host, command):
  ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % host, command],
                         shell=False,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

and here is an example of what I am doing:

```
executeRemoteCommand(user@machine1, "cd /dcd-netapp1/test/test-priority_v6; ./prerun")
time.sleep(30)  
executeRemoteCommand(user@machine2, "cd /dcd-netapp1/test/test-priority-v6; ./run")
time.sleep(1800)
executeRemoteCommand(user@machine1, "cd /dcd-netapp1/test/test-priority-v6; ./postrun")
executeRemoteCommand(user@machine2, "cd /dcd-netapp1/test/test-priority-v6; ./graph_results")
```

The problem is that my `prerun` ssh session is not killed off. The `postrun` script takes care of killing the logging scripts that were started with the `prerun` script, but like I said, the ssh session shows up well after the test is over when I look at all running processes with `ps -ef | grep ssh`

For some additional information, I used to have this code within the `executeRemoteCommand` function:

```
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
if result == []:
  error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
  print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
else:
  print result
```

I commented it out because the `prerun` script would hang waiting for std output to be put into result. This never would happen. My `prerun` script does have std output, but I figured it wasn't able to collect it due to it maybe being a sort of daemon process? I don't know very much about the `prerun` script.

Comment: Here's some example code that may be helpful: https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/v3.0.0-rc.1/digits/task.py#L203-L241

Comment: Do you expect your command to terminate? If so, the readlines thing should work. My guess is that ssh is blocked waiting for a password. You can use `ssh-copy-id` to enable passwordless login. There is a program called `askpass` that can help also.

Comment: yes, I expect the `prerun` to terminate when i run the `postrun` script. I have `authorized_keys`. As I think I mentioned, things work just fine without the readlines, but the ssh's don't terminate, usually just the `prerun` but right now at this moment they are all alive and should have ended a long time ago.

Comment: The command runs to completion on the remote side? If you don't care about what happens on the ssh connection, you can use `nohup` to run in the background. Its a good idea to get rid of pipes also, so something like `subprocess.Popen("nohup", ["ssh", "%s" % host, command], shell=False, stdout=open(subprocess.DEVNULL, 'wb'),       stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`

Comment: Is ssh on the local machine a zombie? `ps x` entry as a "Z"?

Comment: yes, the commands finish or are finished with the postrun script killing them. the ssh is left for dead on the local machine that I start the test on. I don't think it is the exact definition of a zombie and `ps x` doesn't do anything but give me a usage error or illegal argument error if I type `ps -x`. I'll try the nohup and close the pipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the pipes is what worked for my scenario. Now, I get all the output from the remote machines on the machine I start the test from and everything closes out gracefully. By the way, I figured out that `shell=False` is false by default so it's unnecessary and so is the `%s % host` string substitution. Here is what it would look like pertaining to my exact question:

```
def executeRemoteCommand(host, command):
  ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", host, command])
```

Since the function was now super simplified, I went a step further and figured the test was easier to read if I got rid of the function entirely and used `Popen` directly:

```
subprocess.Popen(["ssh", user@machine1, "cd /dcd-netapp1/test/test-priority-v6; ./prerun"])
time.sleep(5)
subprocess.Popen(["ssh", user@machine2, "cd /dcd-netapp1/test/test-priority-v6; ./run"])
time.sleep(1800)
subprocess.Popen(["ssh", user@machine1, "cd /dcd-netapp1/test/test-priority-v6; ./postrun"])
subprocess.Popen(["ssh", user@machine1, "cd /dcd-netapp1/test/test-priority-v6; ./graph_results"])
```

Comment: to avoid zombies, you have to call `.wait()` method eventually or if you want to call the commands sequentially then use `subprocess.check_call(['ssh', ...])` instead of `subprocess.Popen() + time.sleep()`.